# Codeigniter sql query refuses to update a column while updating 2 others in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

Basically this sql query has suddenly stopped working properly, and it still returns that a row has been updated, because it has, but it refuses to update a column of varchar while updating ints

I've tried through both the codeigniter query builder & just straight up writing the sql.

Additionally printing last_query() & pasting that into the sql executor in phpmyadmin updates all columns normally

Oddly the query did execute properly, once, after adding echo comments, however removing broke it again & replacing them didn't fix it again, also changing the order of the query has no effect, even if the varchar column is first in the update it still only updates the two int columns

Effectively the query is 'UPDATE table SET intColumn = int, intColumn2 = int, varcharColumn = string' and the query does execute properly in admin so I'm fairly certain it's not a syntax error & the weirdest thing is this code has worked for longer than 2 months, but now doesn't

Even directly saying 'update table set varchar = string' doesn't work

This is using php 7.3.2 x64 apache 2 in Xammp

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Wheres the code? `update table set column = "value"`  isn't the same thing as `update table set column = value`

Comment: @jarrod can you show your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll get a much better response - and better chance of solving your problem - if you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).